# How can I configure a server in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, seam, openbravo

When I start my Tomcat server, I am getting a problem described by the error messages listed below.

How can I resolve this problem?

```
Aug 5, 2010 10:25:13 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:openbravo' did not find a matching property.
Aug 5, 2010 10:25:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/server:/opt/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9.1:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib
Aug 5, 2010 10:25:13 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

and this exception also:

```
[main] WARN  org.jboss.seam.security.permission.PersistentPermissionResolver  - no permission store available - please install a PermissionStore with the name 'org.jboss.seam.security.jpaPermissionStore' if persistent permissions are required.
Aug 5, 2010 10:25:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.openbravo.dal.core.DalContextListener
org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: Not able to create domain type org.openbravo.userinterface.selector.model.domaintype.ModelElementDomainType for reference org.openbravo.base.model.Reference [id: 45B39681AFBC4808A64C9B776A290BA4, name: OBUISEL_SelectorFieldPropertySelector]
```

Comment: What exact Eclipse, WTP and tomcat versions are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:openbravo' did not find a matching property.

This doesn't harm. Eclipse is just adding an extra attribute to Tomcat's `<Context>` element to be able to associate the deployed webapp with a particular project. Tomcat is just jerking because it don't recognize it as one of the predefined `<Context>` attributes. It's however trying to be helpful for the case the enduser actually made a typo and so on. Just ignore it. You won't see it when you export the webapp and deploy it on a real production server.

> [main] WARN  org.jboss.seam.security.permission.PersistentPermissionResolver  - no permission store available - please install a PermissionStore with the name 'org.jboss.seam.security.jpaPermissionStore' if persistent permissions are required.
>   Aug 5, 2010 10:25:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart

I'm no Seam guy, but [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22warn+org.jboss.seam.security.permission.persistentpermissionresolver+-+no+permission+store+available+-+please+install+a+permissionstore+with+the+name+%22) learns me that you may get this when you've configured your JPA to use JTA transactions and didn't configure `<security:jpa-permission-store>` in Seam's `components.xml`. To fix this, either add the permission store or configure JPA to use resource local transactions only.

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.openbravo.dal.core.DalContextListener
>
> org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: Not able to create domain type org.openbravo.userinterface.selector.model.domaintype.ModelElementDomainType for reference org.openbravo.base.model.Reference [id: 45B39681AFBC4808A64C9B776A290BA4, name: OBUISEL_SelectorFieldPropertySelector]

This is a custom/wrapped exception which doesn't give much helpful information away. We're more interested in the root cause of the exception. Look further in the stack trace for the *root cause* part of this exception. It will tell about the, uhm, root cause of the problem :)

---

Nonetheless, none of the problems as far are related to the literal question *"How to configure server in Eclipse?"*. You seem to already have done it successfully. The first problem is ignorable. The second problem is related to Seam/JPA. The third problem is related to Openbravo ERP. You may consider to ask *separate* questions about them to fix the one and other.